# MPAndroidGraph How to make the graph auto-scroll

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart in my application and I am generating points in real-time and adding them to the graph. 
How do I make the view "follow" the graph and move as new values are added ?
In the sense, that once the graph reaches the right end of the screen(x value is maximum), the graph should move forward and allow the user to swipe back to see the older part of the graph.

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible, please have a look at the [realtime-chart-demo](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/RealtimeLineChartActivity.java), it explains how to do it.

- Set an empty `LineData` (or whatever data) object for the chart:

  `chart.setData(new LineData())`
- Call this method everytime you add an entry:

  ```
  private void addEntry(Entry entry) {

      LineData data = mChart.getData();

      if (data != null) {

          // get the dataset where you want to add the entry
          LineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

          if (set == null) {
              // create a new DataSet if there is none yet
              set = createSet();
              data.addDataSet(set);
          }

          // add a new x-value first
          data.addXValue("somestring");
          data.addEntry(entry, 0);

          // let the chart know it's data has changed
          mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

          // limit the number of visible entries
          mChart.setVisibleXRange(6);

          // move to the latest entry
          mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount()-7);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: But how to handle zoom in case line graph update every second and zoom checking one line by zooming it .but when i am making update graph it loss position of current view which uses is viewing .